# Validation using ValidationGroup when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, code-behind

I am trying to write code for my button that checks the validation controls in "infoGroup" when the next button is clicked in my wizard.

When I click the next button, it goes to the next step in the wizard, skipping over the validation controls. It should not go forward if the required fields are empty or if they have invalid values but it does. I had this working before I added them to a validationGroup but I need to use validationGroup because I need to do client side validation and server side validation (when the button is clicked).  Below is my code for my validation and my code behind for when the next button is clicked:

```
<tr>
    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text="Name:"  CssClass="LabelText"></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"  CssClass="TextBox" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="nameRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your name."
        CssClass="errorMessage"
        ControlToValidate="TextBoxName"
        Text="*"
        SetFocusOnError="true"
        Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationGroup="infoGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="nameRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid name."
        ControlToValidate="TextBoxName"
        ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z\.\'\-_\s]{1,40}"
        Text="*"
        CssClass="errorMessage"
        SetFocusOnError="true"
        Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationGroup="infoGroup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelEmail" runat="server" Text="E-mail:"  CssClass="LabelText"></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail" runat="server"  CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="emailRequiredFieldValidator"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email address."
                      CssClass="errorMessage"
                      ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail"
                      Text="*"
                      SetFocusOnError="true"
                      Display="Dynamic"
                      ValidationGroup="infoGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emailRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address."
                      ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail"
                      ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                      Text="*"
                      CssClass="errorMessage"
                      SetFocusOnError="true"
                      Display="Dynamic"
                      ValidationGroup="infoGroup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </td>
</tr>

protected bool Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{ 
    Page.Validate("infoGroup");
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Validation group is not related with allowing client and server validation. You can validate on both places without a validation group. Why do you think that?

Comment: Try putting `e.Cancel` in your else statement

Comment: i dont't see Wizard1_NextButton button control in the html you posted, please post complete code

Comment: true, check that the asp button tag has the attribute ValidationGroup="infoGroup" too